# How to deploy spring boot web application in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, db2, websphere, weblogic12c

When deploying into weblogic, we add weblogic.xml file in spring boot application.
Similarly what are the required files to be added in application to deploy in websphere 8.5.5

Comment: Many hits on google, e.g. https://medium.com/@james.tran/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-2-x-apps-on-websphere-8-5-5-d0b2e257f606

Comment: I think it's better to phrase the question, after you posted some links of documentation in which you tried getting an answer but failed to do so

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar thing long time ago.

You can just build it as normal war file. unless you required specific IBM resources

Following a copy of a pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>quickweb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>quickweb</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```